# How to run R codes inside shell script?

Tags: r, shell, sh

I have a R file ( myfile.R). I want to run it using a shell script. How Can I do that?
I tried this:

```
#! /bin/bash
Rscript myfile.R
```

but it gives me this error: Rscript: command not found

I also tried this:

```
#! /bin/bash
R --not-save-- < myfile.R
```

It also gives this error: R : command not found

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: formatting made a difference there. It's likely that R is not in your PATH environment variable. Can you run R from the command line by just typing `R`? Is `bash` your default shell?

Answer (score 6):

The idea is to *not* write a shell but to write an *R* script. That is what `Rscript` is for, and our [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) package offered `/usr/bin/r` even before that.

So just do

```
 #!/usr/bin/Rscript

 cat("Hello, world\n")
 # rest of your code below
```

or use

```
 #!/usr/bin/r
```

for [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) -- I have multiple cron jobs doing just that.

This obviously assumes that you'd have `Rscript` or `r` in `/usr/bin` as you would e.g. on a regular Debian or Ubuntu box.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is batch mode. You can do that, like this:

```
R CMD BATCH [options] infile [outfile] &
```

You can read more about batch mode [here.](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/BATCH.html)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Cygwin on Windows:

```
#!/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/R/R-3.3.0/bin/x64/Rscript.exe

# dummy example

cat("Hello StackOverflow\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Start R with the command `R` and then just add youre code

```
user@ubuntu:~/RCode/RCode$ R
> source("data_acquisition.R")
> load_libraries()
> df <- acquire_nps()
> head(df)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have installed R in your machine (Linux based), I feel below are the steps you can follow to run R in sh file.

OS : Mac-Os (Mojave version)

R-version : 3.6

**step 1** : I have installed R in my mac machine using brew.

$ brew install r  (-- This will install latest R into your machine --)

**step 2** : create sample sh file. (startR.sh)

$ touch startR.sh

**step 3** : copy below contents into your startR.sh file

$ vim startR.sh

(Paste below contents)

```
#!/bin/sh
Rscript sample.r
echo " r sample run"
exit
```

( --- I have created simple R file with name sample.R with below contents --)

sayHello <- function(){

print('hello')
}

sayHello()
[image]

( This is simple hello function, please feel free to change this with your actual functions)

note : please place your sample.R in same location as that of startR.sh

**step 4** : change permission to .sh file

$ chmod 750 startR.sh

**step 5** : execute .sh file

$ sh startR.sh

If everything goes fine, it should print below output.

During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LneB2.png) "hello"
 r sample run

[image]